# Cannot update a varchar with string that includes a dot(.)

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have a quite weird error in SQL.
I am trying to update a database field using pyodbc library in python.
the query is the following:
`UPDATE companyies SET primary_domain='vilatec.com' WHERE codi= '1c44f4dd-b54c-4982-9eaa-b1baef92a65f';`
As you can see, the vilatec.com is a string. This actually updates on my database but then I get the error: `The multi-part identifier 'vilatec.com' could not be found`
It looks like it is not reading the vilatec.com as a string, but if it was a reference, but anyway it updates. What do you recommend to do? is there a way to refer the character . so it doesn't catch the error or should I ignore this exception?

Connection:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=server, user=user_db, password=password, database=database)
cur = connection.cursor()
```

This is the code:

```
query = """UPDATE companyies SET primary_domain='vilatec.com' WHERE codi= '1c44f4dd-b54c-4982-9eaa-b1baef92a65f';"""
execute_sql(query,cur,connection)

def execute_sql(query,cur,connection):
    cur.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
```

The original query was:

```
query = """UPDATE companyies SET primary_domain ='{0}' WHERE codi= '{1}';""".format(primary_domain, company_id)
```

where primary_domain is 'vilatec.com'

Comment: Are you certain you didn't forget the quotes? (`'`). Does the error say "found" or "bound"?

Comment: Hi! yeah, I am printing the query to make sure it has the single quotes. I couldn't tell you if it says found or bound since the answer is in Spanish. I writted found because it is what I saw in most of the questions over internet. If you want the literal error is: El identificador formado por varias partes 'vilatec.com' no se pudo enlazar. 4104

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the code used to reproduce the error?

Comment: Edited the original post. Didn't add connection part as I know it works, but if you need I add it. EDIT: just added

Comment: Can you try `query = """UPDATE companyies SET primary_domain=? WHERE codi=?;"""` and then `cur.execute(query, 'vilatec.com', '1c44f4dd-b54c-4982-9eaa-b1baef92a65f')`? The way you currently have it opens yourself up to SQL Injections.

Comment: Yeah already tried, but I get the same error, so that's why I thought adding the format and the single quotes would work

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is using `query = """UPDATE [companyies] SET [primary_domain]=? WHERE [codi]=?;"""` but the others should work if your table and field names are correct. Maybe include the full stacktrace as well? That would be helpful in troubleshooting specifically which part is causing the problem. Does it work through SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with & in the past ,this is the way I solved it:

query = "UPDATE companyies SET primary_domain='vilatec"+"."+"com' WHERE codi= '1c44f4dd-b54c-4982-9eaa-b1baef92a65f';"